# Get previous value of an observable in subscribe of same observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, observable

Is it possible in knockout to get the current value of an observable within a subscription to that observable, before it receives the new value?

Example:

```
this.myObservable = ko.observable();
this.myObservable.subscribe(function(newValue){
    //I'd like to get the previous value of 'myObservable' here before it's set to newValue
});
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There is a way to do a subscription to the before value like this:

```
this.myObservable = ko.observable();
this.myObservable.subscribe(function(previousValue){
    //I'd like to get the previous value of 'myObservable' here before it's set to newValue
}, this, "beforeChange");
```

Comment: what does `this` stands for here?

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis It ensures that you can access the same value of "this" inside the callback function. Otherwise you would need to save it to another name beforehand, e.g. var self = this; (which is a perfectly valid strategy too).

Answer (score 154):

```
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeChanged = function (callback) {
    var oldValue;
    this.subscribe(function (_oldValue) {
        oldValue = _oldValue;
    }, this, 'beforeChange');

    this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        callback(newValue, oldValue);
    });
};
```

Use the above like this:

```
MyViewModel.MyObservableProperty.subscribeChanged(function (newValue, oldValue) {

});
```

Comment: fairly new to knockout, but I'm wishing this is the way the default subscribe was setup. Or.. this fn will at least scratch my first itch as I use 'subscribe' for the first time.

Comment: There has been some movement on this on https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/914. Looks like it's slated for the 3.4 release.

Comment: In case the subscribed observable value type is an Array, you have to slice it, otherwise the oldValue will always be the same as the newValue. Check a working example, here: https://jsfiddle.net/david_freire/xmk6u9yn/4/

Comment: Cool. Added a return value which is a subscription object with a `dispose()` function https://gist.github.com/30ff1f5c1adf215179b0046515f86e45

Comment: Oh just saw the git conversation.

Comment: @DavidFreire if the array contains objects it's still broken. I tried to work around it, it's quite messy. In the end I added an additional subscription that handles the value as JSON completely.

Answer (score 23):

Little change to Beagle90 answer. Always return the subscription itself to be able to access the dispose() for instance.

```
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeChanged = function (callback) {
    var oldValue;
    this.subscribe(function (_oldValue) {
        oldValue = _oldValue;
    }, this, 'beforeChange');

    var subscription = this.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        callback(newValue, oldValue);
    });

    // always return subscription
    return subscription;
};
```

Comment: This is a real step up, but calling `.dispose` on the return value from this will only dispose of the second subscription, not the `'beforeChange'` subscription

Answer (score 18):

The [pull request](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/914) to add this feature has some different code that winds up being better than relying on using the `beforeChange` event.

All credit for the solution to [Michael Best](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/914#issuecomment-66697321)

```
ko.subscribable.fn.subscribeChanged = function (callback) {
    var savedValue = this.peek();
    return this.subscribe(function (latestValue) {
        var oldValue = savedValue;
        savedValue = latestValue;
        callback(latestValue, oldValue);
    });
};
```

To quote Michael:

> I originally suggested using `beforeChange` to solve this problem but have since realized that it's not always reliable (for example, if you call `valueHasMutated()` on the observable).

Answer (score 4):

I have found that I can call peek() from a writable computed observable to get the before value.

Something like this (see http://jsfiddle.net/4MUWp):

```
var enclosedObservable = ko.observable();
this.myObservable = ko.computed({
    read: enclosedObservable,
    write: function (newValue) {
        var oldValue = enclosedObservable.peek();
        alert(oldValue);
        enclosedObservable(newValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately, since by the time the subscribe callback is called, the value already changed and so `peek()` will give you the new value.

Comment: @MichaelTeper I know I posted my answer a year ago, but after I got some downvotes, I've just tested it, and it does work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/4MUWp/

Comment: Ok I see what you did there... The question was about retrieving the value in a `subscribe` callback which cannot be done with peek(). Your example proves nothing and could confuse a newcomer. You basically are wrapping a private variable here, and display its value before setting it - so of course it won't have changed.