# What is the `valueWillMutate` for in KnockoutJs?

Tags: knockout.js

One can kick an observable calling its `valueHasMutated` method to force a notification to the subscribers. What does `valueWillMutate` do?

Comment: Why don't you check it out in the source code: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/search?q=valueWillMutate&ref=cmdform?

Comment: Maybe `valueBeforeMutate` would have been a more suitable name

Comment: That name sounds more like a property to get the value from before the last mutation, or something. valueWillMutate happens to trigger an event that passes along the value before mutation, but the function itself has a different responsibility.

Comment: @nemesv because i have SO, where i can get a better answer from a human

Answer (score 9):

When subscribing to an observable, sometimes you want to know the previous value of the observable when it has changed. For example, when you have an observable `selectedItem` (in a list of items), but each individual item also has a `selected` property. When `selectedItem` changes, you want to selected `selected = false` on the previously selected item. You can do that like this:

```
selectedItem.subscribe(function (previous) {
    previous.selected = false;
}, null, 'beforeChange');
```

valueWillMutate is used to trigger the `beforeChange` event.

Edit: for even more utility, take a look at [Knockout-2.2.0, subscribe get value before change AND new value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076865/knockout-2-2-0-subscribe-get-value-before-change-and-new-value). The highest-voted answer creates an extender that allows you to subscribe to an observable and use both the old and new value at the same time.

Edit 2: Just to clarify: you do not need to explicity call `valueWillMutate` to get the `beforeChange` event: Knockout does that for you when you operate on an observable. You only need to do it manually when you operate on the underlying value, or when you want to explicity trigger subscribers for some reason. My answer was written from the point of view of Knockout's internal implementation, which I didn't really make clear.

Comment: Typically, a `beforeChange` event will only fire when an observable is in the process of actually being changed. A direct call to `valueWillMutate` will allow you get that `beforeChange` event to fire without actually changing the observable. To use the OP's own words... it allows you to "kick" the observable's `beforeChange` event.

Comment: I see what you are saying, and that would indeed be correct if it is only used by the end user. But internally Knockout uses the valueWillMutate function a lot. Also, if you operate on the underlying value of an observable, the `beforeChange` event will not fire. In this case, you have to do it yourself. Operating on the underlying value often makes sense from a performance aspect, especially on observableArrays. Nevertheless your comment is a useful addition to my answer, as my answer might imply to the reader that you always have to call valueWillMutate yourself to get the beforeChange event

Comment: I certainly wasn't trying to dispute your answer. I was just trying to re-enforce it by putting it in slightly different terms. That is why I added it as a comment to your answer rather than as a standalone answer. :)

Comment: And I'm glad you did. The answer is more complete now. Thanks :)